# Convert input data set

Tags: r

I am working on requirement where the input data is in below format.

```
Name XYZ AGE 30 Country India Mobile 1234567890
Name ABC AGE 35 Country Russia Mobile 2345678901
```

I want to import this data into R & want to reshape it . i.e. "Name" "AGE" "Country" "Mobile"  should be the column header .

Comment: How is the data stored? is it in a text file? How are the fields delimited?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

How about you create a data frame first with the values and then add the names as follows,

```
x <- c('Name XYZ AGE 30 Country India Mobile 1234567890',
           'Name ABC AGE 35 Country Russia Mobile 2345678901')

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(x, ' '), function(i) i[c(FALSE, TRUE)])))
names(df) <- unlist(strsplit(x[1], ' '))[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
df
#  Name AGE Country     Mobile
#1  XYZ  30   India 1234567890
#2  ABC  35  Russia 2345678901
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data is stored in a data.frame `df1`

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Name XYZ AGE 30 Country India Mobile 1234567890
                        Name ABC AGE 35 Country Russia Mobile 2345678901")
```

You could create a new data.frame `df2` by selecting every second (even-numbered) column

```
df2 <- df1[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
```

and assign the column names by using every second (odd-numbered) entry in the first row of `df1`:

```
colnames(df2) <- unlist(df1[1, c(TRUE, FALSE)])
```

The data.frame `df1` can then be deleted with `rm(df1)`. This is the result for `df2`:

```
#> df2
#  Name AGE Country     Mobile
#1  XYZ  30   India 1234567890
#2  ABC  35  Russia 2345678901
```

---

The same procedure could be written as a one-liner. Arguably less clear, but certainly more compact:

```
df1 <- `colnames<-`(df1[c(FALSE,TRUE)], unlist(df1[1,c(TRUE,FALSE)]))
```

In that case the second data.frame `df2` is not needed.

Comment: Worked for me..Thanks.. Trying the other suggestions also..will update here with the results..

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `matrix` and `unlist` should do the trick. Like

```
tidyData <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(dataByLine), nrow=length(fileByLines), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=F))
```

If you had a minimum reproducible example, this would be easier to answer